# Passing a boolean result into another methods if statement. (tic-tac-toe game)

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, tic-tac-toe

```
public boolean isWinner(char player)
{
        if (board[0] == player && board[1] == player && board[2] == player ||
            board[3] == player && board[4] == player && board[5] == player ||
            board[6] == player && board[7] == player && board[8] == player ||
            board[0] == player && board[3] == player && board[6] == player ||
            board[1] == player && board[4] == player && board[7] == player ||
            board[2] == player && board[5] == player && board[8] == player )
            return true;

  return false;  
}
/* check to see if the player x is the winner or
   the player y is the winner or the cat is the winner 
    or the game is not over yet  and then display the result
     you need to write conditional statments*/
public void displayResults()
{
  if (isWinner = true)
     System.out.print("CONGRATUTIONS " + player + " YOU WON!");
}
```

Hey I was wondering if anyone could help me on how to pass the the "isWinner" result into "displayResults" if statement. This is for a tic-tac-toe game that we got assigned if this is one of the parts I need help on.

Comment: You need to look at some basic tutorials for java. Try googling something like `get return value of method java `

Comment: Pass as a argument to `displayResults()` method? Come-on it's so basic, you need to try some java tutorials first.

Comment: how are you returning 0 and 1 when the method requires boolean ?

Comment: yea about the 1 and 0 sorry I was working with some ideas I had and forgot to revert those

Comment: isWinner = true is not the same as isWinner == true

Answer (score 1):

Running under the assumption that `player` is an accessible `char` object...

```
public void displayResults()
{
  if (isWinner(player))
     System.out.print("CONGRATULATIONS " + player + " YOU WON!");
                          // ^^^^
                          // Fix your typo too
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `isWinner` should return `true` or `false`, not 1 or 0.

Second of all,

```
if (isWinner = true)
```

should be

```
if (isWinner(player))
```

assuming `player` is a char that represents a player, since that's what `isWinner()` requires.

Comment: yea about the 1 and 0 sorry I was working with some ideas I had and forgot to revert those